# How can post multiple arrays using JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to post multiple arrays to my controller using Ajax post.  First I have a model like this:

```
     public class EnrollmentOptionsVM
     {

   public virtual string OptionID{ set;get;}
   public virtual string UserChoice { set;get;}
   public virtual string TchOptionID { set; get; }
   public virtual string TeacherChoice { set; get; }

    }
```

Then my script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var $strInstructors = $('input[name="instructorString"]');
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#saveBtn').click(function () {

                var teacherOptions = [];
          var options = [];
          $.each($checkboxes, function () {
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                  var item = { "UserChoice": "checked", "OptionID": "YouCanSetIDHere" };
              }
              else {
                  var item = { "UserChoice": "unchecked", "OptionID": "YouCanSetIDHere" };
              }
              options.push(item);
          })
          $.each($strInstructors, function () {
              if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                  var tchItem = { "TeacherChoice": "checked", "TchOptionID": "SetTchIDHere" };
              }
              else {
                  var tchItem = { "TeacherChoice": "unchecked", "TchOptionID": "SetTchIDHere" };
              }
              options.push(tchItem);
          })
          $.ajax({ type:
'POST', url: '@Url.Action("EnrollmentRefresh", "Student")',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: JSON.stringify({firstArray:options, secondArray:teacherOptions})
          }).done(function (html) {

          });

      });
      });



        </script>
```

And in my controller here’s the action signature:

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnrollmentRefresh(List<EnrollmentOptionsVM> checkedOptions)
    {}
```

When I send only options like this: data: JSON.stringify(options)… it works but when I try to send multiple arrays like the code above it returns null in the controller.  How can post multiple arrays using JSON.stringify()?

UPDATE 1

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var $strInstructors = $('input[name="instructorString"]');
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#saveBtn').click(function () {

                var teacherOptions = [];
          var options = [];
          $.each($checkboxes, function () {
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                  var item = { "UserChoice": "checked", "OptionID": "YouCanSetIDHere" };
              }
              else {
                  var item = { "UserChoice": "unchecked", "OptionID": "YouCanSetIDHere" };
              }
              options.push(item);
          })
          $.each($strInstructors, function () {
              if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                  var tchItem = { "TeacherChoice": "checked", "TchOptionID": "SetTchIDHere" };
              }
              else {
                  var tchItem = { "TeacherChoice": "unchecked", "TchOptionID": "SetTchIDHere" };
              }
              teacherOptions.push(tchItem);
          })
          $.ajax({ type:
 'POST', url: '@Url.Action("EnrollmentRefresh", "Student")',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: JSON.stringify({checkedOptions:options,selectedTeacher:teacherOptions})

          }).done(function (html) {

          });

      });
      });



        </script>
```

And in the controller:

```
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult EnrollmentRefresh( List<EnrollmentOptionsVM> checkedOptions,   List<TeacherOptionMV> selectedTeachers)
    {}
```

Two ViewModels
     public class TeacherOptionMV
    {

```
    public virtual string TchOptionID { set; get; }
    public virtual string TeacherChoice { set; get; }
}
```

And

```
         public class EnrollmentOptionsVM
         {

       public virtual string OptionID{ set;get;}
        public virtual string UserChoice { set;get;}


       }
```

Comment: Can you post the controller method with the two arrays?

Comment: your selectors look good. did you try checking them in a debugger to see if they get populated?

Answer (score 1):

You are not posting multiple arrays with `{firstArray:options, secondArray:teacherOptions}`. You are posting a single object with two properties: `firstArray` and `secondArray`. Your controller is designed to get only one array of `EnrollmentOptionsVM`. The best thing to do, I guess, is to change `EnrollmentRefresh` method to take some object with fields `firstArray` and `secondArray` (or something like that) as an argument.

Comment: Tried everything I could think of...still only one array was sent.  I'll keep looking.